# Matlab convex optimisation toolbox. Optimisation variable not shown

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization

I'm using the convex optimisation toolbox in matlab and the objective function gets minimized and the value is shown. But the optimisation variable for which minima is achieved, I cannot find. Will someone tell me how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say which function you are using to perform the optimization, but most or all of them return the location of the minimum as the first argument. See [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) for example.

Comment: Alright. Found it. Thanks.